# how to boost nested object with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have mapped my index as below. Simply I have a product index with properties Id, Number,ManufactureNumber,shortDescription, name and nested object like SubProduct

```
"mappings": {
 "Product": {
"properties": {
    "id": { "index": "no","store": true,"type": "integer"},
    "name": { "store": true,"type": "string"},
    "image": { "properties": { "fileName": { "index": "no","store": true,"type": "string"},"virtualPath": { "index": "no","store": true,"type": "string"}}},
    "number": { "index": "not_analyzed","store": true,"type": "string"},
    "manufactureNumber": { "index": "not_analyzed","store": true,"type": "string"},
    "subProduct": { "type": "nested","properties": { "name": { "store": true,"type": "string"},"number": { "index": "not_analyzed", "store": true,"type": "string"},"Id": { "index": "no","store": true,"type": "integer"}}}
    }
    }
    }
```

what I want here is to search a keyword within properties of name, Number, ManufactureNumber,shortDescription and SubProduct.name, SubProduct.number. So if keyword is found any of this document should be returned with following priorities (scores)

- manufactureNumber = 5.0
- number             =4.0
- name=2.0
- subproduct.number=2.0
- subproduct.name   =1.0

Based on those requirements and after my research, I thought multimatch query with boosting is my only option. Am I correct on this? or any query_string query can do it as well?
This is how I tried but I got stuck in the part with the nested object. I dont know how to boost them? below code will give error that number and name are not properties of subproduct.

```
var results = Client.Search<Product> (body => body.Query(query => query.MultiMatch(qs =>
qs.OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d.Add(entry => entry.manufactureNumber , 5.0)
   .Add(entry => entry.number , 4.0)
   .Add(entry => entry.name,3.0)
   .Add(entry => entry.subproduct.number,2.0)
   .Add(entry => entry.subproduct.name,1.0)
 ).Type(TextQueryType.BestFields).Query(key))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Nested Query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) when querying on nested fields. In your case, they are `subProduct.number` and `subProduct.name`. The query you might be interested in is as under:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "type": "best_fields",
            "query": "key",
            "fields": [
              "manufactureNumber^5",
              "number^4",
              "name^3"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "type": "best_fields",
                "query": "key",
                "fields": [
                  "subProduct.number^2",
                  "subProduct.name^1"
                ]
              }
            },
            "path": "subProduct"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The corresponding Nest query is as under:

```
var results = client.Search<Product>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                sh => sh.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                    .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                        .Add("manufactureNumber", 5.0)
                        .Add("number", 4.0)
                        .Add("name", 3.0))
                    .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                    .Query(key)),
                sh => sh.Nested(n => n
                    .Path("subProduct")
                    .Query(nq => nq
                        .MultiMatch(qs => qs
                            .OnFieldsWithBoost(d => d
                                .Add("subProduct.number", 2.0)
                                .Add("subProduct.name", 1.0))
                            .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                            .Query(key))))))));
```

Comment: must "should" be used for a bool query with boosting? or "must" can be used as well or does it even make sense?

Comment: For what you want, a `bool should` is the only way to achieve it. You may have to tweak boost values a bit to achieve the desired ranking.

Comment: Using your query worked fine but there is a case for example, I have a subproduct called "HL-2230" but none of them main product has name including both "hl" or "2230". when give hl-2230 as key, it returns first products having either hl or 2230 in top 10. I want this product with subproduct having full name returned in the first? how can I tweak my query to achieve this?